# Improve performance for setting Ivar

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have swizzled the default setters for an objective-c class to allow for some kind of KVO without actually adding an observer to a property. This works fine. But in some cases, I need to assign hundreds of thousands of properties around this system.

Thus, for performance reasons, I have a custom property descriptor which allows to set the ivar directly. In an attempt to tune performance I save some info about the property.

One remaining place, which I'm rather careful about changing, is the use of object_setIvar(), which account's for 60% of CPU time during assignment according to Instruments. 
The culprit is object_setIvar is calling _class_getVariable, which takes 3 times longer than the actual assignment (objc_storeStrong()).

Long story short: Since I can cache all info to the class' property in advance as part of my property descriptor, how can I set the ivar faster (avoiding object_setIvar())?

Here is the actual object setter function of my property descriptor class (there is also an equivalent for setting numeric values):

```
- (id)setObjectValueNoKVOForOwner:(id)instance newObject:(id)newObject
{
    Class cls = object_getClass(instance);
    BOOL retainNewValue, copyNewValue, releaseOldValue;
    switch (self.setterSemantics)
    {
        case MemberDescriptionSetterSemanticsAssign:
            retainNewValue  = NO;
            copyNewValue    = NO;
            releaseOldValue = NO;
            break;

        case MemberDescriptionSetterSemanticsRetain:
            retainNewValue  = YES;
            copyNewValue    = NO;
            releaseOldValue = YES;
            break;

        case MemberDescriptionSetterSemanticsCopy:
            retainNewValue  = NO;
            copyNewValue    = YES;
            releaseOldValue = YES;
            break;
    }

    if (!_ivar)
    {
        _ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(cls, self.attributes.ivarName);
    }

    if (_ivar)
    {
        id oldObject = object_getIvar(instance, _ivar);
        if (newObject != oldObject)
        {
            if (retainNewValue)
            {
                newObject = [newObject retain];
            }
            else if (copyNewValue)
            {
                newObject = [newObject copy];
            }

            object_setIvar(instance, _ivar, newObject); // Improve this: avoid _class_getVariable

            if (releaseOldValue)
            {
                [oldObject release];
            }
        }
    }

    return [newObject autorelease];
}
```

**Update:**

I've found sources related to object_setIvar(): 
https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/master/runtime/objc-class.mm
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-private.h
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm

It wouldn't seem "that" evil to implement an own version of object_setIvar(), just adding the known class as an argument to it. Unfortunately it requires a private header file. As I target iOS it seems I should give up hopes at this point.

**Update 2:**

I found this comment at the place where it wastes time in the Apple sources:

"// FIXME:  this could be optimized."

So I should probably give up at this point and hope it will be improved in future. I actually really don't understand that there is such a bottleneck within something as basic as setting a value to a property. On the other hand, glad to see that programmers at Apple are also just human beings :).

Answer (score 0):

> hundreds of thousands of properties around this system

While I'm not an expert on this topic, my undertanding of **processor-memory bus** inner workings suggests that it's much better to change **nearby values** (L1-3 cache hit) rather than values that are far away from each other (L1-3 cache miss).

Therefore wouldn't you be better with simple *continuous* C arrays of your values for fast storage?

Comment: I should have mentioned I write an ORM. There I create entities and set values fetched from a db to class properties (classes are unknown there, so I use property descriptors to know about properties). Similar to CoreData objects and descriptors, though not the same.

Comment: I should also mention that I actually have another optimization in place to avoid creating all entities (using a cursor). Still, I have one requirement where I at one point need to create that many entities at once.

Comment: So you know the memory layout of your objects and type of the property. Why not call `objc_storeStrong(location, value)` directly?

Comment: That was my first thought as well, looking at what object_setIvar() does. But for example I won't know about wether the actuall class uses ARC or not. Something you can only know by using private methods.

Comment: But if you use only values fetched from a db, won't your values be basically scalars and `NSString` (perhaps+`NSArray`...)? And I thought you control the instance class?

Comment: No, that won't work. The entity class is under "user" control, the ORM only knows it by a one time created descriptor per entity class. Potentially the entity could have an NSArray as property (for lazy invoked relations).